# Do We Need Separate Tags for 'tips' and 'advice'

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed both of these tags, and they seem to be the same?  I propose a tag alias from 'advise' to 'tips'.  Thoughts?

Comment: Do it. ` ` ` ` ` `

Comment: I've merged the two tags and created a tag synonym between them.

Answer (score 2):

Neither should be a tag. Tips and advice/advise are indicative of forum-style discussions and have no place on a Stack Exchange site.